# Magento 2: How to reset filters in product grid?

Tags: magento2, products, filter

I have changed per page setting to `500` in **Catalog Product Grid** page. It could not load that much of product and gave me error. Now it is somehow saved in somewhere, and every time I visit the Product Grid page, it cannot load products and gives error.

How can I reset the filter settings in Product Grid page?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The filter settings are stored in `ui_bookmark` table. It has the following columns:

- `bookmark_id`,
- `user_id`,
- `namespace`,
- `identifier`,
- `current`,
- `title`,
- `config`,
- `created_at`,
- `updated_at`

You can delete the row with your `user_id`, or just truncate that table.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use https://github.com/magenizr/Magenizr_ResetUiBookmarks which does exactly the same what you have explained above. This module will add a reset button on the *Account Settings* page in the backend. Once you hit the *Reset UI Bookmarks* button, it will delete all records from `ui_bookmark` based on the current `user_id`.